# Bootstrap flush to footer doesnt work correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am trying to flush my footer to the bottom of the page. I have tried the official bootstrap method listed on http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html which only seems to work on pages that have some amount of content. On pages with a short amount of content, it actually pushes the footer past the bottom of the page and creates scroll bars.

Sorry if the post if done badly. Ive never posted here before and it took me a while to figure it out.

[Picture 1 shows the main body](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2d_Ggw_TFAva1NZeGNITXQ2elE/view) and there is no visible footer as it is past the bottom of the page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/camera.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/easy-responsive-tabs.css">
<!--JS-->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
<script src="js/camera.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.camera_wrap').camera();
    });
</script>
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <div style='text-align:center'><a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-    explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." /></a></div>  
  <![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../docs-assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><!    [endif]-->

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">  
<!--header-->
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand navbar-brand_"><a href="index.html"><span>Smile Hawthorn</span></a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 follow-box">
          <div class="box2">
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" target="new"><button type="button" class="btn btn-book btn-lg">
<span class="fa fa-calendar-header">BOOK ONLINE</button></a></li>

            </ul>
              <p class="tel"><span class="fa fa-phone-header"></span></p>

            </div>
            <div class="box1">
                <p>Please click  <strong>Book Online</strong> or <strong>Call</strong> our clinic for an appointment. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-box">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top tm_navbar clearfix" role="navigation">
            <ul class="nav sf-menu clearfix">

              <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>

                <li  class="active sub-menu"><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a><span></span>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="staff.html">Our Staff</a></li>
                        <li><a href="values.html">Our Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="technology.html">Our Technology</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                  <li class="sub-menu"><a href="index-2.html">Services</a><span></span>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Emergency</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fillings<span></span></a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Composite</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">CEREC</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Amalgam</a></li>
                            </ul> 
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Crowns/Caps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Root Canal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Whitening</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wisdom Tooth Removal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Veneers/Bonding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Orthodontics</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="index-2.html">F.A.Q</a></li>
                <li><a href="index-3.html">Pricing</a></li>
                <li><a href="index-4.html">Location</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>

<!-- Content -->
<div class="global indent">


    <div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2 banner-box2">
            <div>
                    <p class="title" align="center"><span>About Us</span></p><p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p class="description" align="center"><a href="staff.html">Our Staff</a></p>
                  <p class="description" align="center"><a href="values.html">Our Values</a></p>
                  <p class="description" align="center"><a href="technology.html">Our Technology</a></p>

            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-10 banner-box2">
            <div>
                <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br>
                  conse ctetur adipisicing elit, sed <br>
                  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut <br>
                labore et dolore magn</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div> 
     </div>       


</div>
</div>

<!--</div> <!-- end wrap-->
<div id="push"></div>-->


<div id="footer"><!--footer-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><!-- First Row First Coloumn -->
                <p class="text" align="left"><span class="fa fa-home-footer"></span><span class="footer_txt"> testing 123</span></p>
       </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><!-- First Row First Coloumn -->
               <p class="text" align="center"><span class="fa fa-phone-footer"></span><span class="footer_txt"> testing 123</span></p>

      </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4"><!-- First Row First Coloumn -->
              <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-10"> <!-- nested 2 coloumn in First Row -->
        <p class="text" align="right"> <span class="fa fa-envelope-footer"></span><span class="footer_txt"><a href="index-5.html"><span style="color: #000;">  Email Us</span></a></span></p>

      </div>

    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row clearfix"> 
        <div class="col-md-12 column"> <!-- second row -->
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>


</div><!-- end footer Div -->


<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tm-scripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

i used the following CSS

```
body {
    line-height: 1.42857;
    font-family: 'Roboto', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
html{
    height: 100%;
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
      #wrap {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
        margin: 0 auto -100px;
      }
#push{ /* height must be the same as #footer height */
     height: 100px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-position: top;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(../img/footer.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: Why are you still using Bootstrap 2? I recommend migrating to Bootstap 3.
http://getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: Hi how do you know I'm using bootstrap 2?

Comment: You said in the question: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/sticky-footer.html

Comment: Oh that was just the example i found for the sticky footer that kind of worked

Comment: Still using BT 3 is better it has many new functions

Comment: Thanks Mramaa, i'll check and make sure im using BT3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I know of to push down the footer in all cases is the following:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
footer {
    height: 100px;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/z21nz89d/7/)

Comment: Thanks Tricky12. It works really well. I tried all these other ways that were on stackoverflow and none of them worked well. YOU ARE A LIFESAVER

Comment: Could you explain why you think my version did not work?

Comment: At a quick glance, I believe that your problems were: 1) you did not need the "push" div; 2) you have 3 heights on your "wrap" - min-height: 100% is the only one you need; and 3) you added margin to your "wrap" for the footer, but did not include padding - meaning that the footer would not be fully pushed to the bottom of the page.

Comment: that makes sense. I was using another example from someone else on stackoverflow and it worked, but only for content that fit the page perfectly or was excess.. Thanks Tricky

Comment: Hi, It works as a general rule, but sometimes when there are other bootstrap jquery items like an tab-accordion or a carousel, the above code doesnt work and the footer sits high.